# How can I know when a form is shown?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, compact-framework

I'm developing a **Windows Mobile 5.0 or above** with **.Net Compact Framework 2.0 SP2** and **C#**.

I have a WinForm that only has a Custom Control. I want to call a method of that custom control when the form has finished loading and display the control.

Now I using Activated Event, but these event is thrown everytime when I close a messagebox.

Is there an event thrown in that moment?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use the activate event and have a boolean in your form that is set to true when you have called the method on your custom control. When the form's activated event is triggered again, you just make a check on this boolean.

Comment: I thought it was a bad design use a global boolean variable to run my code once on activated event.

Comment: If you use this hack, wouldn't you have to manage the boolean during the entire lifetime of the form?

Comment: It's not a global variable, it's local to the form only. Is that bool a lot to manage? don't think so. It's normal to have a bool in a class to tell wether it has initialized or it is disposed and other things. Standard .NET forms have a lot of properties telling us about its states. Is 'IsDisposed' a hack? No, I don't think so. –

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have a **Shown** event in the Compact Framework, but you should be able to use the **Load** event. Set your form's **Visible** property to true and you should be able to access your custom control after that.

```
MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ' this procedure runs only once, when the form loads
    ' make the form visible to the user now
    this.Visible = true
    ' the form is now visible

    ' ... more code
}
```

Comment: As you can see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx
Load event occurs before a form is displayed for the first time. I want to call this method when the form and its control are displayed.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that Load happens first. However setting this.Visible = true; in the Load event should be a viable work-around.

Comment: I don't understand you. How can I access my control after setting Visible = true. I understand the control is created with this property set to false. And then I set up to true on Load event, isn`t it?

Comment: Your form has a Load event. Inside the load event set your forms visible property = true. Your form will immediately be visible to the user, kind of the same thing as having a Shown property. Now you know the form is loaded and visible for the first time - you can do what ever it is you are trying to do when the form is shown and this will only happen once.

Comment: It sounds like you’re explicitly setting the form to be visible.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did:

1) Create a dummy, empty pictureBox control on the form

2) Use a boolean variable to tell when the pictureBox's Paint event is called after the form's Load event and call my own OnShow() function

```
public partial class MyForm: Form
{
    bool form_shown = false;

    private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form_shown = true;
    }

    private void pictureDummy_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (form_shown)
        {
            MyOnShow();
            form_shown = false;    
        }
    }
}
```